# Javascript - Array with Boolean Keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, boolean

I'm relatively new to Javascript, and there's probably just a trick I'm not familiar with, but how can I assign boolean values to Array keys?

What's happening:

```
var test = new Array();
test[false] = "asdf";
test['false'] = "fdsa";

Object.keys(test); // Yield [ "false" ]
Object.keys(test).length; // Yield 1
```

What I want to happen:

```
var test = new Array();

//Some stuff

Object.keys(test); // Yield [ "false" , false ]
Object.keys(test).length; // Yield 2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use arbitrary indexes in an array, but you can use an object literal to (sort of) accomplish what you're after:

```
var test = {};
test[false] = "asdf";
test['false'] = "fdsa";
```

However it should be noted that object properties *must* be strings (or types that can be converted to strings). Using a boolean primitive will just end up in creating an object property named `'false'`.

```
test[false] === test['false'] === test.false
```

This is why your first example's `Object.keys().length` call returns just `1`.

For an excellent getting started guide on objects in JavaScript, I would recommend MDN's [*Working with objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: This is good to know. Maybe I'm just too spoiled for working mainly in PHP for the last year. I don't suppose I could have an array object with numeric and "associative" keys at the same time, could I? Basically, I need an array that holds single-level arrays, and if a user belongs to a certain group, a key is created in the upper-array to hold the lower-array of user information within that group, and if they're not a part of a group, they need to default to a "blank" group. The problem is that the group could be named anything, so I'd like this "blank" key to not be a string.

Comment: You can name object properties integers (`var obj = { }; obj[1] = 'foo' }`). Typically you would use an object and then create a property of *that* object that's an array: `var obj = { }; obj.ArrayProp = [];`. Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you. People like you are the reason I love this site.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Javascript aren't associative, **so you cannot assign values to keys in them.**

```
var test = [];
test.push(true);  // [true]
test.push(false); // [true, false]
```

**You're interested in an Object!**

```
var test    = {};
test[true]  = "Success!";
test[false] = "Sadness";  // {'false': "Sadness", 'true': "Success"}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Array is an Object and it can have keys just like any other Object :)

Answer (score 2):

you could also reverse the answer above such as

```
let test = [true];

console.log(typeof test);

// Output: Object True
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript arrays are only number index based. You could use 0 and 1 as keys (although I can't think of a case where you need boolean keys). `myArr[0] = "mapped from false"; myArr[1] = "mapped from true";`